# Does aiohttp support HTTPS proxies

Tags: python, https, proxy, http-proxy, aiohttp

When I try to make a request through an HTTPS proxy-

```
async with session.get(
    url
    headers={"k": v},
    proxy='https://my-proxy.com:1234',
) as response:
    resp_json = await response.json()
```

My request fails with the following exception:

```
raise ValueError("Only http proxies are supported")
```

This corresponds to the [source code](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py#L467) .

However, [the docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#proxy-support) say that HTTPS proxies are supported.

Is this an oversight in the docs or am I doing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 5):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4100) in the repo and Andrew Svetlov was kind enough to clarify. `aiohttp` supports plain HTTP clients and HTTP clients that can be upgraded to HTTPS via HTTP CONNECT. I made a [pull request](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/pull/4101) to update the docs.