# How do I use HTTPS proxy with aiohttp?

Tags: python, proxy, aiohttp

How do I use HTTPS proxy with `aiohttp` in Python?

I have seen the [docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/client_advanced.html#proxy-support) where it is said I need to upgraded to HTTPS via the HTTP CONNECT method. But I have not found any complete Pythonic example how to do it? I have also viewed the questions [Using https proxy with aiohttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810994/using-https-proxy-with-aiohttp) and [Does aiohttp support HTTPS proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103076/does-aiohttp-support-https-proxies). They refer to the original documantation without details.

Let's suppose I have an HTTPS proxy with IP 1.2.3.4 and port 3128 and I want to request https://stackoverflow.com/ through it. How would the Python code (using asynchronous `aiohttp`) for it look like?

I tried this with the error:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def main():
    proxy = f"https://1.2.3.4:3128"
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://stackoverflow.com/", proxy=proxy) as response:
            print(response)

asyncio.run(main())
```

The error:

```
ValueError: Only http proxies are supported
```

Comment: If you must connect to the proxy via HTTPS, then it's not supported, as written in [the documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#proxy-support). If your proxy allows connections via HTTP and then aiohttp can negotiate an upgrade of the connection, that'll work. Just pass `"http://..."` as the proxy address then.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. There is no way to force use of HTTPS explicitly?

Comment: Apparently not. Why is that important? If the target site is HTTPS, the connection (end to end, between Python and the target) will get upgraded to HTTPS anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn off the ssl_context to http server, see this thread for more information https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/206

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as client:
    async with client.get(
        proxy=url,
        url=server_url,
        data=b"Test content!",
        ssl_context=None,
    ) as resp:
        ...
```